# how to annotated a column with a column from another dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to do the following in r:

df1 is

```
symbol assession.number ensembl.id value  
N/A NM_001954   ENSG00000204580 6.173531  
RFC2    NM_002914   ENSG00000049541 6.613105  
PAX8    NM_013951   ENSG00000125618 8.793348
```

df2 is

```
assession.number symbol   
NM_001954   DDR1  
NM_001954_2 DDR1  
NM_001954_3 DDR1  
NM_001954_4 DDR1
```

I was wondering if there is a way fill N/A in df1 with the symbol in df2?
Thanks in advance!

Kun

Comment: do a left join the coalesce the symbol columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` :

```
inds <- df1$symbol == 'N/A'
#Use is.na if you have actual NA value and not string "N/A"
#inds <- is.na(df1$symbol)
df1$symbol[inds] <- df2$symbol[match(df1$assession.number[inds], df2$assession.number)]
df1

#  symbol assession.number      ensembl.id    value
#1   DDR1        NM_001954 ENSG00000204580 6.173531
#2   RFC2        NM_002914 ENSG00000049541 6.613105
#3   PAX8        NM_013951 ENSG00000125618 8.793348
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It works perfectly and easy to understand!

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    left_join(df2, 'assession.number') %>%
    mutate(symbol = ifelse(grepl('N/A', symbol.x), symbol.y, symbol.x))%>%
    select(-symbol.x, -symbol.y)

  assession.number      ensembl.id    value symbol
1        NM_001954 ENSG00000204580 6.173531   DDR1
2        NM_002914 ENSG00000049541 6.613105   RFC2
3        NM_013951 ENSG00000125618 8.793348   PAX8
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It works with 'NA' but not work with actual NA value. And I was wondering if you can explain a little bit of these codes? Thanks again!